# Grep pattern to find lines whose 5th character is a digit

Tags: regex, grep

I am to find lines in a file whose fifth character is a digit. That is, of the digit set {0123456789}. I made a file that had:

```
asdf1
asdf2
```

.. and so on until 0.
I made a few more cases with special characters, and other symbols just to make sure I wasn't grabbing those lines either.

However, one thing intrigued me. When making the line:

```
SSSSS3
```

or

```
TTTTTS7
```

that is, where every S is a space, and T is a tab, that line is also retrieved when the fifth character is a space/tab and not a number.

Could anybody explain why this is happening?
The pattern I'm using is

```
'....[0-9](.)*'
```

If I'm not mistaken, a '.' represents any character, right? How could more than 4 tabs or spaces count as less than 5 '.'?

Comment: If you had lines in the file like 'abcdef4', those would be found too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the start-of-line anchor:

```
^....[0-9]
```

Without it, `egrep` performs a regexp *search* rather than a regexp *match*, as if you had entered

```
.*....[0-9]
```

though with the difference that the `.*` does not cause capturing for flags like `-o`.

(Note that the `(.)*` at the end is also useless. `.*` is implicitly appended to the end of the RE unless you put in an end-of-line anchor, `$`.)

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thanks for the info! Egrep is indeed.. different. ;)